# AngularJS ng-grid for large datasets

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs

Can you please suggest how can I display a dataset with about 20K records with say for example grid scrolling?

The problem I am facing is that the json sent by web service exceeds the maxJsonLength.
I have tried changing the web.config to use the following

```
 <configuration> 
 <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
```

I have also tried changing the serializer's maxJsonLength

```
 serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```

but the json is even bigger than that.

I have tried using this http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/402_GridIsScrolling but I dont think it addresses the issue when json length is bigger than max.

Please suggest this or any other way I can render the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paging and if you don't want to have paging button then you can use virtual scrolling.

ng-grid support virtual scrolling in configuration options ( setting for  virtualizationThreshold ) . Or you can also use kendo grid http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data

This will mean that your webservice need to support paging.